# Boot sector constantly getting corrupted

Tags: windows-10, boot, bootloader

This problem started a few weeks ago : PC randomly freezes (maybe once in a week or more), becomes completely unresponsive and has to be powered off. After that windows can't be booted. It tries to repair the system but always fails. The only thing that helps is plugging in an USB drive with windows image and entering these commands in command prompt:

bootrec /FixMbr

bootrec /FixBoot

bootrec /RebuildBcd

After this windows starts working. I've tried formatting my SSD and performing a clean installation a few times but still the problem persists. I've checked SSD with Samsung Magician and it's healthy. Also ran Windows Memory Diagnostics tool to check RAM and it had no errors. I tried using memtest86 but my PC just can't boot it. (boot priority is correct and it tries booting from flash drive but ends up stuck on a black screen with a flickering underscore). My RAM usage seems to be high most of the time (85%+). And after reinstalling Windows a new partition appeared out of the blue. It seems to be from my SSD and is only 500mb.  Any ideas what is going on with my PC?

Specs:

OS: Windows 10 64-bit

Motherboard : P7P55 LX (LGA1156)

CPU: Intel Core i7 870 @ 2.93GHz

Storage: 
465GB Seagate ST3500418AS ATA Device (SATA ),
232GB Samsung SSD 850 EVO 250GB (SATA (SSD)) (Windows installation)

Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 970.

[image: Image of my partitions]

Comment: Download and Run Crystal Disk Info, and read out the SMART. Sounds like your SSD is dying.

Comment: Best partition layout on the system drive on BIOS motherboards are 1) WinRE (512MB), (2) Boot (300MB), (3) Windows System (this must be manually configured via `DiskPart` during Windows Setup).  Regardless of the order, WinRE can be accessed without a USB drive _(via Settings > Update >  Recovery - Advanced Startup, via login screen: hold down SHIFT while clicking Restart, or via powering off the system twice in a row once Windows begins to boot)_.  The only thing that could cause boot corruption would be a failing drive  or malware. Also, OP must be set via the Magician software.

Comment: Crystal Disk Info says that both drives are healthy. I'm using SATA controller for my SSD. Maybe that's the failing part?

Comment: @JW0914 agreed. I'll remove my comments too.

Comment: @N999th The more likely cause is malware, as you'd be experiencing issues on other partitions if this was hardware related.  Unless you mounted `F:` for troubleshooting, it should never be mounted in Windows for a reason other than troubleshooting or maintenance of the `WinRE.wim`.  Run `chkdsk f: /offlinescanandfix`.  If that doesn't return any issues found, boot up an Antivirus boot disk and scan all drives... beyond that, you'll likely need to seek support on a forum ([Malwarebytes](https://forums.malwarebytes.com/), [MSFN](https://msfn.org/board/), etc.) , as this requires troubleshooting.